# Hide option values from select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code for my select list

```
<select class="select" type="text" name="groupName">
<option value="Internal"> Internal </option>
<option value="administrators">administrators</option>
<option value="developers">developers</option>
<option value="users">users</option>
</select>
```

I need to hide the Internal group from the list on a particular page.
I am trying to do this using the name of the select list but this does not work can someone please guide me.
I cannot add id to the existing code that is the reason I need to hide the option based on the select name.

Comment: `$('select[name="groupName"] 'option[value="Internal"]')...;`

Comment: you mean you want to hide option available in name="groupName" like want to hide one option out of four?

Comment: as @MauricePerry pointed out, hiding options is not cross-browser compatible. You may need to detach the options inside. if you want it back you need to store the the childrens first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attribute selector.

```
$('[name=groupName] option[value=Internal]').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks adil and @abhitalks this solved my issue . It was so simple :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe that only firefox allows the hiding of individual <option>s in a <select>. Chrome, Safari and IE don't.

Comment: Thanks Maurice , I need to make this compatible on IE too but i dont have latest IE installed on my machine .Can you guide me howw to make it work on IE too?

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to remove the options instead of hiding them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [**attribute value selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and remove option

```
$('.select[name="groupName"] option[value="Internal"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select the particular option and remove:

```
$('.select option[value=="Internal"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try alternative way,

```
 $("select[name='groupName'] option").eq(1).remove();
```